# Infinitive vs Present Participle in this sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I had an English test today, which had a question like this -

> The king had many occasions ________________ (experience) the power of the writing on the paper during his reign.

Just for context, here's the part just before the sentence —

> Once a king asked a hermit for a powerful talisman. The hermit gave him a ring containing a folded slip of paper and asked him to open it whenever faced with an extraordinary situation, be it a tragedy or a triumph. The talisman, the hermit told the king, would keep him grounded and would help him keep his head in any situation.

And here's what's after —

> The paper had on it a simple line: "This, too, shall pass."

I wonder what can be filled in the blank. Is `to experience` correct? Or is it `experiencing`? Or both? Please also explain why.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I think that would give a different sense than what is intended. I guess **had** is supposed to be the main verb. And the sentence implies that the king, after being given the talisman, had several occasions on which he realized its power.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No I don't mean that "required"-sense either. What I think is that the para implies — the king got a talisman. Several times later in his life, he realised its power. **had**, I think, is in the sense of "witnessed an event". Does this seem clearer? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: If we understand **occasions** as "opportunities" then it is as Dr Sitecode has answered, and **on** is not necessary, contrary to my (now deleted) comment above. That is rather an old meaning for the word, from the 18th century, although it is still used in that way from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

It should be "to experience":

**The king had many occasions to experience...**

In this sentence the word **occasion** means "opportunity"